# Retornar dados de pesquisa no banco em JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

Estou desenvolvendo uma interface que deve retornar em uma `JTable` os valores de uma tabela mysql. Desenvolvi o seguinte método:

```
public class Teste extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JTable table;
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

    public Teste() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void popularJtable(String sql) {

        try {
            Connection con = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            modelo = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

            modelo.addColumn("tipoCurso");
            modelo.addColumn("nomeCurso");

            while (rs.next()) {
                modelo.addRow(new Object[]{
                    rs.getString("tipoCurso"),
                    rs.getString("nomeCurso")
                });
            }
            table = new JTable(modelo);
            jScrollPaneCursos = new JScrollPane(table);
            stmt.close();
            con.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPaneCursos = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        Pesquisar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Pesquisar.setText("Pesquisar");
        Pesquisar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                PesquisarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(59, 59, 59)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPaneCursos, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 264, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(146, 146, 146)
                        .addComponent(Pesquisar)))
                .addContainerGap(77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(93, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(Pesquisar)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPaneCursos, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(66, 66, 66))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void PesquisarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String sql = "SELECT tipoCurso, NomeCurso FROM curso";
        popularJtable(sql);
    }                                         

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Teste().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton Pesquisar;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPaneCursos;

}
```

A idéia é chamar esse método dentro de um botão pesquisar, onde passo uma string com o script mysql (é um select nesse caso). Porém, aponta o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

e aponta para a linha:

```
modelo = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
```

Comment: Refiz o projeto, testei e o problema continua o mesmo e na mesma linha. A tabela que era para aparecer era a tabela curso, que tem as coluna idCurso, tipoCurso e nomeCurso.

Comment: Em qual linha agora?

Comment: modelo = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando recuperar um model de uma tabela que nem foi criada ainda. Esta é a causa do *nullpointer*, a variável `table` está nula.

Nem tem como sugerir nada porque esse novo código não faz muito sentido, mas se você não cria a tabela já populada quando a aplicação inicia, remova essa linha:

```
modelo = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
```

Uma vez que o modelo já foi instanciado como `DefaultTableModel` junto com a classe.

Apesar dessa correçao não ter a ver com a pergunta inicial, do jeito que esse codigo está, nao irá exibir a tabela, e não ha necessidade de instanciar uma nova tabela ou adicionar ela ao container com scroll cada vez que for feita uma pesquisa. Então altere as linhas:

```
table = new JTable(modelo);
jScrollPaneCursos = new JScrollPane(table);
```

para:

```
table.setModel(modelo);
```

Mova a adição da tabela ou para o construtor da classe ou adicione uma validação que impeça a linha abaixo de configurar mais de uma vez a tabela como *viweport* do JScrollPane:

```
if(jScrollPaneCursos.getViewPort().getView() == null) {
    jScrollPaneCursos.setViewportView(table);
}
```

Também será necessário instanciar a tabela no campo respectivo:

```
private JTable table =  new JTable();
```

Para exibir dados novos na tabela não é necessário recria-la e nem adicioná-la mais de uma vez ao container. `JTable` em si é apenas um componente visual, quem gerencia os dados dentro dela é o model, portanto, basta alterar o model que os dados serão exibidos e modificados.

Comment: Essa alteração solucionou  a exceção nullpointer, entretanto, ainda não aparece a tabela.

Comment: Eu pretendo, que depois de acionar o botão pesquisar, a tabela apareça carregada com os registros.

Comment: @Costa.Gustavo editei a resposta, mas sugiro que da proxima pergunta sempre seja claro e objetivo na suas duvidas, fornecendo um exemplo minimo.

Comment: Obrigado Articuno, vou tentar ser mais claro da próxima vez. A paz esteja com você.

Answer (score 0):

O trecho abaixo está incorreto. Primeiramente temos que instanciar o objeto table(JTable) para poder utilizar seus atributos

```
modelo = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        modelo.addColumn("tipoCurso");
        modelo.addColumn("nomeCurso");
        while (rs.next()) {
            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{
                rs.getString("tipoCurso"),
                rs.getString("nomeCurso")
            });
        }
        table = new JTable(modelo);
```

Segue abaixo o modo correto:

```
table = new JTable(modelo);
modelo = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        modelo.addColumn("tipoCurso");
        modelo.addColumn("nomeCurso");
        while (rs.next()) {
            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{
                rs.getString("tipoCurso"),
                rs.getString("nomeCurso")
            });
        }
```